# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta con Firebase en Android?

Tags: android, firebase

Quisiera preguntar como podría realizar la siguiente consulta básica que tenemos normalmente en SQL, pero ahora con las opciones de filtrado que nos proporciona Firebase.

---

El ejemplo es el siguiente, tenemos la siguiente tabla:

**Usuarios**

- Nombre : varchar2
- Email : varchar2
- telefono: number

La consulta de ejemplo en SQL seria:

```
SELECT Nombre FROM Usuarios WHERE Email LIKE '%gmail%';
```

Mi duda es la siguiente: Imaginemos que la anterior tabla "*Usuarios*" tiene mil millones de registros y que con la anterior consulta SQL conseguimos que nos devuelva los usuarios que tienen el correo electrónico con gmail. (es solo un ejemplo nada más).

---

Ahora quiero hacer esto mismo en Firebase. Quiero que me devuelva de entre los mil millones de usuarios aquellos que tengan en su campo "email" por lo menos la palabra "gmail" ya sea al inicio, al final o entre medio del String.

No quiero que me devuelva una snapshot de toda la base de datos ni que me devuelva una lista de los 100 primeros ordenados por valor o lo que sea. Quiero exactamente los usuarios que tienen una clave "email" cuyo valor contenga la palabra "gmail" en sus valores.

Contenido en la base de datos en Firebase:

```
db:
   001:
      nombre: "juan",
      email: "juan@gmail.com",
      telefono: 123456789
   002:
      nombre: "pepe",
      email: "pepe@hotmail.com",
      telefono: 832729828
   003:
      nombre: "maria",
      email: "maria@outlook.com",
      telefono: 736292723
   004:
      nombre: "lucia",
      email: "lucia@gmail.com",
      telefono: 738682934
```

Quiero obtener **sólo** el Nombre "juan" y "lucia" que son los que cumplen con la consulta (no quiero todo la raiz de "juan" ni de "lucia", porque podrian tener mil atributos y yo sólo quiero saber sólo el atributo "Nombre" de los que cumplen mi filtrado).

Comment: Creo que no podes, te dejo un post en ingles que tambien lo preguntan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589092/firebase-query-find-item-with-child-that-contains-string a bajo del todo tenes un link que te lleva a una pagina donde podes tener una solucion, pero no lo que queres